# create a one page PDF from two PDFs using PDFBOX

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a small (quarter inch) one page PDF I created with PDFBOX with text (A). I want to put that small one page PDF (A) on the top of an existing PDF page (B), preserving the existing content of the PDF page (B). In the end, I will have a one page PDF, representing the small PDF on top(A), and the existing PDF intact  making up the rest (B).  How can I accomplish this with PDFBOX?

Comment: Have you tried anything? What problem made you stop?

Comment: @mkl I tried to do an addPage. Created new page at the end of PDF B.  Tried to strip the data from PDF B to determine if there is data in the right hand corner. Returned blanks, suspected because PDF B is created from TIFF image.  Researched overlay, could not get any  examples to work for me. I did create the equivalent of a cover page with the text (A)on it to proceed the PDF B. Regulations do not allow a cover page.  Pretty much out of options that is why I quit. New to JAVA and PDFBOX so difficult to formulate my own solution without seeing a working example Thanks.

Comment: Seems that overlay is the ticket. Again after spending hours hitting the wall trying multiple examples, back to where I started again! Maybe it is impossible. It certainly appears that way for me.

Answer (score 0):

To join two pages one atop the other onto one target page, you can make use of the PDFBox `LayerUtility` for importing pages as form XObjects in a fashion similar to PDFBox `SuperimposePage` example, e.g. with this helper method:

```
void join(PDDocument target, PDDocument topSource, PDDocument bottomSource) throws IOException {
    LayerUtility layerUtility = new LayerUtility(target);
    PDFormXObject topForm = layerUtility.importPageAsForm(topSource, 0);
    PDFormXObject bottomForm = layerUtility.importPageAsForm(bottomSource, 0);

    float height = topForm.getBBox().getHeight() + bottomForm.getBBox().getHeight();
    float width, topMargin, bottomMargin;
    if (topForm.getBBox().getWidth() > bottomForm.getBBox().getWidth()) {
        width = topForm.getBBox().getWidth();
        topMargin = 0;
        bottomMargin = (topForm.getBBox().getWidth() - bottomForm.getBBox().getWidth()) / 2;
    } else {
        width = bottomForm.getBBox().getWidth();
        topMargin = (bottomForm.getBBox().getWidth() - topForm.getBBox().getWidth()) / 2;
        bottomMargin = 0;
    }

    PDPage targetPage = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(width, height));
    target.addPage(targetPage);


    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(target, targetPage);
    if (bottomMargin != 0)
        contentStream.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(bottomMargin, 0));
    contentStream.drawForm(bottomForm);
    contentStream.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(topMargin - bottomMargin, bottomForm.getBBox().getHeight()));
    contentStream.drawForm(topForm);
    contentStream.close();
}
```

*([JoinPages](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/JoinPages.java#L51) method `join`)*

You use it like this:

```
try (   PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDDocument top = ...;
        PDDocument bottom = ...) {
    join(document, top, bottom);
    document.save("joinedPage.pdf");
}
```

*([JoinPages](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/JoinPages.java#L39) test `testJoinSmallAndBig`)*

The result looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you. Compile errors occurring. The variable Matrix cannot be found.  Should the ... in PDDocument top= and bottom= be replaced with the names of the PDFs (test testJoinSmallAndBig)? Doing that by passing in parameters is giving me  incompatible types: String cannot be converted to PDDocument..

Comment: *"The variable Matrix cannot be found."* - Matrix is no variable, it is a class. You're most likely missing the required imports. Follow the links under the code for a complete test class. *"Should the ... in PDDocument top= and bottom= be replaced with the names of the PDFs (test testJoinSmallAndBig)?"* - not their names but PDDocument instances they are loaded into. *"Doing that by passing in parameters is giving me incompatible types: String cannot be converted to PDDocument"* - obviously.

Comment: _The variable Matrix cannot be found_ There should be an item "fix imports" in your IDE, search it. In Netbeans, the keyboard shortcut is CTRL SHIFT i. In Eclipse it is CTRL SHIFT o.

Comment: @TomDeskevich Have you meanwhile got the code running?

Comment: @mkl  Actually pretty close. I am passing in my text and it is adding it to the top of the existing PDF on page 1. I need to research and play around with the rectangle size and position for the small page. The text has to be in the right side of the small page. Also only writing page 1 to the new PDF, not all the pages.

Comment: *"Also only writing page 1 to the new PDF, not all the pages."* - in your question I read "In the end, I will have a one page PDF" after you "put that small one page PDF (A) on the top of an existing PDF page (B)". According to that both source documents only provide a single page each to the process.

Comment: @Tom *"The text has to be in the right side of the small page."* - you did not mention anything on that in your question, so I naturally centered horizontally.

Comment: @mkl Was just happy to get the text on top. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an additional point to @mkl's answer.
If anybody is looking to scale the PDFs before placing them on the page use,

```
    contentStream.transform(Matrix.getScaleInstance(<scaling factor in x axis>, <scaling factor in y axis>));  //where 1 is the scaling factor if you want the page as the original size
```

This way you can rescale your PDFs.

Comment: Where should we inject that exactly and how should the parameters look like? Could you please explain a bit more as I am unfamiliar with this? Thanks!

Comment: Where should we inject that exactly and how should the parameters look like? Could you please explain a bit more as I am unfamiliar with this? Thanks!